# Pause Approval Workflow until further information is supplied

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Hi I have a Power Automate custom approval workflow linked to a SharePoint list where there are 3 options:

1)Approve
2)Reject
3)More information is required

The first 2 are straight forward but am not sure how to deal with the one requiring more information - I want the requester to be notified that the approver wants more info and then the approval is paused and then the approver is notified once the extra info is supplied. I have managed to get it to notify the creator that more info required via email but really I want the Workflow to pause and restart once the info is supplied. Is it possible to do this or is it better to look at some other solution outside the approval connectors?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, this should be a manually triggered workflow. Regarding your thought, this cannot be done automatically. I have a suggestion for your reference:
When the option is: More information is required, then explain the situation via the email: the creator knows what information is needed, fill in the information when applying again, and then manually trigger the workflow.
And the workflow can end at the next step when the email is sent.